# Python - iterate and change elements of a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have just started learning python and am having trouble with iteration and if statements.

I have a list `d`:

```
d = ['s','u','p','e','r','c','a','l','i','f','r','a','g','i','l','i','s','t','i','c','e','x','p','i','a','l','i','d','o','c','i','o','u','s']
```

I need to iterate through the list and check whether each element is equal to a vowel(`a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`). If it is a vowel then that element must be replaced with a sub-list with the word `'vowel'` preceding the letter. For example if `'a'` is detected, it would be replaced with `['vowel', 'a']`.

This is what I've managed to think of so far although although I know it is incorrect:

```
for items in d:
    if items == 'a':
        d[items:items] = ['vowel', 'a']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were quite near, this is the minimal edit required.

```
for items in d:
    if items in {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}:
        d[d.index(items)] = ['vowel', items]   # Get the index of the element, then replace 
print(d)
```

Comment: Use  `{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}` ;)

Comment: well `0(1)` is always better than  `0(n)` unless I am counting money ;)

Comment: Do you have a link to a  blog on this i.e. sets vs tuples vs lists? Too many people get confused ... Need a link badly

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks ... (But the dreaded tuple is missing ... *sigh* )

Comment: tuples are cheaper to construct than a list I imagine but still just as linear when you go looking in one!

Answer (score 5):

For check the membership you can use `in` operand and for replace you can loop over your list with `enumerate` :

```
>>> for i,item in enumerate(d) :
...   if item in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') :
...              d[i]=['vowel',item]
... 
>>> d
['s', ['vowel', 'u'], 'p', ['vowel', 'e'], 'r', 'c', ['vowel', 'a'], 'l', ['vowel', 'i'], 'f', 'r', ['vowel', 'a'], 'g', ['vowel', 'i'], 'l', ['vowel', 'i'], 's', 't', ['vowel', 'i'], 'c', ['vowel', 'e'], 'x', 'p', ['vowel', 'i'], ['vowel', 'a'], 'l', ['vowel', 'i'], 'd', ['vowel', 'o'], 'c', ['vowel', 'i'], ['vowel', 'o'], ['vowel', 'u'], 's']
>>>
```

Comment: To be clear, I'm pretty sure the `['vowel', 'a']` was only for the letter 'a'.  It should use whatever vowel was present.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
[['vowel', i] if i in 'aeiou' else i for i in d]
```

Comment: This creates a new list.

Answer (score 2):

Try it out:

```
for key, l in enumerate(d):
    if l in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
        d[key] = ['vowel', l]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over the length range is much cheaper. You can avoid element lookup which will cost you an extra `0(n)`.

```
for index in xrange(len(d)):
    if d[index] in 'aeiou':
        d[index] = ['vowel', d[index]]
```